# Greenleaf archive library?

Tags: compression

Our products use the [Greenleaf Archive Library](http://www.greenleafsoft.com/), an old compression library for Windows. We're now looking to move to the mac, but I'm pretty sure the .lib files we got from Greenleaf won't work on that platform.

Other than just switching to another compression library, which would be problematic for several reasons, does anyone know of any alternatives, like an open source version of the library or a mac port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2.12 version of ArchiveLib we've got here shipped with full source code and builds fairly painlessly under various compilers.
Check your original install package and see if it has an option to install the source.

---

Edit (much later): As I mentioned in the comments, there was one missing method in the source code. As the link I put there seems to have vanished, I've added the code below.

```
//
// void ALStorage::YieldTime()
//
// ARGUMENTS:
//
//  None.
//
// RETURNS
//
//  Nothing.
//
// DESCRIPTION
//
//  This function has two important things to do.  It gets called
//  at a few different points in the process of reading or writing data
//  from storage objects.  During normal reading and writing, it
//  will get called every time the buffer is loaded or flushed.
//
//  If we are in Windows mode, we execute a PeekMessage() loop.  This
//  makes sure that we aren't hogging the CPU.  By doing it this way,
//  the programmer can be ensure that he/she is being a good citizen
//  without any significant effort.
//
//  The second important function is that of calling the monitor function.
//  The user interface elements need to be updated regularly, and this
//  is done via this call.
//
// REVISION HISTORY
//
//   May 26, 1994  1.0A  : First release
//

void AL_PROTO ALStorage::YieldTime()
{
    if ( mpMonitor )
        mpMonitor->Progress( Tell(), *this );
    /*
     * For right now I am going to put the PeekMessage loop in the load
     * buffer routine by default.  Most Windows applications are going
     * to want to use this, right?
     */
#if defined( AL_WINDOWS_GUI )
    MSG msg;

    while ( PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ) ) {
        TranslateMessage( &msg );
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
#endif
}
```

Comment: Actually, it wasn't FULL source code. One function is missing: ALStorage::YieldTime(). Fortunately, a google search on the method name turned up a copy at http://svn.softwarepublico.gov.br/trac/lightbase/browser/LBS/LIBS/AL101/CPP_ALL/STORAGE.CPP?rev=35&format=raw

Comment: any chance you still have the sourcecode and could tell me what the hell the level 4, ALGlCompression thing actually is? The company is defunct and it ended up underpinning a format I'm working with to no avail.

Comment: From what I remember, the actual compression code was obfuscated by all of the variables/methods/etc having useful names like _251 and never stated what algorithm it was using. So it may be quite a lot of work to figure it out even if I can find the source.

Comment: There is a Rust package that claims to be an implementation of the library. The file you are probably most interested in is: https://github.com/software-opal/archivelib-rs/blob/master/archivelib-sys/c-lib/src/_re.cpp

Comment: It's a bridge to the dll file. You still need the dll, and it doesn't do anything, itself.

Comment: Oh, hm. It's actually not. I always thought embroidermodder just reverse engineered the code, and that's why it looked so absurd.

https://github.com/Embroidermodder/libembroidery/blob/master/emb-compress.c

I hadn't considered that that is what the source actually looked like. Seriously though, thanks this is actually crazy helpful. Might be some ways to stab this white whale.

Answer (score 0):

Greenleaf Archive Lib has some source code that exists which is obfuscated into various functions. Today with modern IDEs you can do a pretty good job fixing this by refactoring things. I also spoke with Mark Nelson who worked with it and he notified that they had sublicensed the code from Robert Jung who wrote ARJ (Archive Robert Jung), since that time ARJ source code has been made available though I find no acceptable license for it, but I can confirm the archiving is the same. Except that Greenleaf has a smaller sliding window.

```
Compression Parameters
The HUS/VIP compression does seem to use the ARJ decode (1 to 3) with a dictionary size of 1024 instead of 26k.

Parameter   Value
CODE_BIT    16
THRESHOLD   3
MAXMATCH    256
DICBIT  10
DICSIZE 1024
NT  19
TBIT    5
NP  15
PTABLESIZE  256
PBIT    5
NC  511
CTABLESIZE  4096
CBIT    9
NPT 19
```

https://community.kde.org/Projects/Liberty/File_Formats/Husqvarna_HUS

Now, the parameter DICSIZE in ARJ is 22k rather than 1k. But, also the value NC is 510 in ARJ rather than 511 as it is with Greenleaf. The decode compression parameter changes the dictionary size. Namely each level of extra compression goes up by a power of 2. It's actually setting the size by a bit shift.

I don't see any properly licensed stuff so you may have to rewrite the arj compression scheme from scratch. Although technical details are sparse, and the source code itself is weird. Apparently he got a now expired patent on the weird part where he's apparently doing some hash tables to do the Huffman encoding by building some tables elements in memory and using them to index find the next index. It appears to be an LZSS scheme using an optional providing of a dictionary. But, the actual workings of the algorithm is very much like like with zip's deflate scheme, it might actually be spot on for deflate. So if compiling some obfuscated source code you might not have isn't possible for some reason you can rewrite it.

---

I rewrote the decompression from scratch, and MIT licensed code:

https://github.com/EmbroidePy/pyembroidery/blob/master/pyembroidery/EmbCompress.py

This will also work for ARJ compression since I didn't care about the window size. It'll read any size window since it will just read the data in the file.

For the compression I don't want to do the massive legwork of writing a real scheme so I've developed a special way to cheat. We write a fake table of 256 8 bit long entries. They will natively number lowest first in a tie so they will exactly map to be equal to the character themselves.

```
Block writing.

16 bits filesize

- Writing Character_Length huffman.
5 bytes: 00000, we have 0 entries. 1 length. They are all 8.
5 bytes: 01010, all values are 10, meaning length 8.
---- CharLength huffman only returns 10.

- Writing Character Huffman.
9 bits: 100000000, 256 entries.
---- All character build with c_len value 10, which is 8. No bits are read.
---- Huffman table of 256 8 entries.

Distance Huffman. (we are never using this).
5 bits: 00000 No entries.
5 bit: 00000 Any value doesn't matter. Since we're never using it.
```

However!

```
45 % 8 = 5
16 + 10 + 9 + 10 = 45 bits.
And we'd have to offset all of our bytes by 3 bits.

So we need a huffman table bit length that is exactly mod 8.
    5 bit: 00001 1 distance huffman.
    3 bit: 111 we have a variable length value 7 or more.
    5 bit: 11110 we add 4 to this 7 for 11. Because really we want to pad bits.

(16) + (10) + (9) + (5 + 3 + 5) = 48 bits. 6 bytes.
2 bytes filesize. Followed by 4 bytes:
0b00000010101000000000000111111110
```

This is storable in a single integer:
`0x02A001FE`

---

So to perform Greenleaf or ARJ compression.

`2-byte-block-size + 0x02A001FE + uncompressed_stream`

If you need more than 2^16 bytes, you'll need more blocks. You make them the same way.

Comment: That sounds like some serious digging you've done there. I'm impressed.

Comment: It was a white whale for me. I coded an uncompress routine in python from scratch. Since ARJ is still copyrighted and the free version had no notice as to the licensing. 

https://github.com/EmbroidePy/pyembroidery/blob/master/pyembroidery/EmbCompress.py

Comment: @NigelHawkins, I'll likely get around to updating this answer. And I've been planning on doing a writeup of the technical specs there. Basically it sends a compressed table that decompresses another table that when you have you do LZSS compression on with some various schemes. The patent etc, applied to the compress routine and doesn't really need to be done since actually maximizing the routine would be rather trivial within a 1k window by just brute force searching.

Comment: And so long as I you stick to the exact encoding it wouldn't be a problem. I've also thought about writing a fake header that encodes 1:1 text. So you can say there are exactly 256 relevant leafs to the tree and it'll build a table that encodes each of those 256 leafs in 8 bytes each. Which would be exactly encoded by the characters themselves. So then I could append uncompressed data and it would work flawlessly. Since it would still be "compressed".